# Is it possible to use only custom filters on a website using uBlock Origin?

Tags: ublock-origin

Website I am interesting in conflicts with filters I have subscribed to but not if I use only custom rules while disabling subscribed filters.

Is there a way to force uBlock Origin to use only custom rules for specific site, ignoring rules from filter subscriptions?